# HPLIP Drive in elementary OS

Tags: software-installation

How can I install HPLIP software in elementary OS?
HPLIP software is not available in their website for elementary as specific.
For Loki, which version of Ubuntu should I choose?

Answer (score 5):

I tried hard to install my HP Laserjet P1102w using HPLIP (3.17.11) but always had error on dependencies. I have running Elementary Os Loki on my laptop.

This video was for great help, but not for the beginning, just for the part of HP GUI at the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UH0-mnpGJI

This is what I did:

A. In a terminal I define the password for root privilegies (**sudo passwd root**), beacuse in some point you are going to need it. In my case, I set the same password that I have for my user account.

B. I use synaptic (you can install it from AppCenter)

C. In synaptic search for HPLIP and install both "HPLIP" and "HPLIP GUI"

D. In the Applications menu, open HPLIP Toolbox.

E. Then use "Set Device" and follow the instructions.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

And that is. It works so fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is already in the Ubuntu repository. Enter `sudo apt-get install hplip` in the terminal to install.

Answer (score 0):

All William did above there is install the version of HPLIP that is already bundled with Elementary. It can be installed using Elementary AppCenter instead of adding Aptitude to confuse things.
You can see that HPLIP is at version 3.16.3 from the screenshot of Aptitude, not 3.17.11.